# Can't access Django Admin with my Custom User credentials

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-custom-user

I created an app 'accounts' from which I created my CustomUser. Then, I created superuser from the command line successfully. But I can't login to Django Admin. Everytime, it displays "Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."

This is my accounts.models file, The only one I modified.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError()
        if not username:
            raise ValueError()

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), username=username)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=None)
        user.admin = True
        user.staff = True
        user.superuser = True
        user.save()
        return user

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=12, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
    objects = MyUserManager()

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_superuser(self):
        return self.superuser
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy-Paste is your problem:

```
def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)  # here was password=None
    # other staff
```